# Call ActionScript function when Javascript's window.onebeforeunload is called

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like to call my function ActionScript closeApp:

```js
public function closeAutorun(event: CairngormEvent): void {
    Alert.show(
        LMSModel.ERR_MESS_QUESTION,
        LMSModel.ERR_MESS_TITLE,
        3,
        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Sprite,
        alertClickHandler);
}
```

When the user close the tab or the navigator.

Any suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript, at the start of your program:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("closeAutorun", closeAutorun);
}
```

In javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmClose;
function confirmClose() {
  document.getElementById('app').closeAutorun();
}
```

where 'app' is the id of the swf instance.